# Find current SkewX, SkewY and Rotate Values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix, rotation

How can I go about finding the current rotation, skewX and skewY transform settings on an element considering that there may be multiple scenarios where only rotate is used, or only skewX is used, etc.

So far, I'm returning the rotation angle just fine:

```
getAngle:function(obj){ 
   var matrix=obj.css("-webkit-transform")||obj.css("-moz-transform")||obj.css("-ms-transform")||obj.css("-o-transform")||obj.css("transform");

   if(matrix!=='none'){
       var values=matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),    
           a=values[0],
           b=values[1],
           angle=Math.round(Math.atan2(b,a)*(180/Math.PI));
   }else{
       var angle=0;
   };
return angle;
}
```

This works out fine, but from reading elsewhere I've learned that as soon as any other transform is applied is messes with the matrix and will cause issues when trying to find a value.

I've read the related links, and they don't seem to have a solution.

So, could this function be modified to handle returning the skewX and skewY values whether or not rotate is set?

Thanks!

Comment: note that recent versions of jQuery will handle the css vendor prefixing for you, so you shouldn't need to specify `-webkit` and `-moz` etc variants in your jquery code; it should work with just `transform`.

Comment: And what is users are on an old version of jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution:

```
var a = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
var qrDecompone = function(a) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(a[1], a[0]),
      denom = Math.pow(a[0], 2) + Math.pow(a[1], 2),
      scaleX = Math.sqrt(denom),
      scaleY = (a[0] * a[3] - a[2] * a[1]) / scaleX,
      skewX = Math.atan2(a[0] * a[2] + a[1] * a[3], denom);
  return {
    angle: angle / (Math.PI / 180),  // this is rotation angle in degrees
    scaleX: scaleX,                  // scaleX factor  
    scaleY: scaleY,                  // scaleY factor
    skewX: skewX / (Math.PI / 180),  // skewX angle degrees
    skewY: 0,                        // skewY angle degrees
    translateX: a[4],                // translation point  x
    translateY: a[5]                 // translation point  y
  };
};
```